# Word VBA for Search/Replace tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a Word 2010 document with 30+ tables, some with text only and the rest financial tables. I need to replace all the financial tables with a [TABLE] placeholder.  How do I use VBA to select the financial tables only?  I figure I could search for numbers (integers) in two adjacent cells, select the table, delete it and replace it with a text placeholder [TABLE] and go on to find the next financial table?  Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub ReplaceTables()
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim oRng As Range
    For Each oTable In ThisDocument.Tables
        If oTable.Rows.Count > 1 And oTable.Columns.Count > 1 Then
            If IsNumeric(oTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Words(1).Text) And _
                        IsNumeric(oTable.Cell(2, 2).Range.Words(1).Text) Then
                Set oRng = oTable.Range
                oTable.Delete
                oRng.Text = "[TABLE]" & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set oTable = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

It loops through all the tables in the document, checks in the first two cells in the second row if the first word is numeric, and if so deletes the table and puts the [TABLE] text and a new line instead.

Hope this helps.

**Addition**:

To check for 4 columns or more, and the presence of a $ sign in the text of the table, use this check instead:

```
If oTable.Columns.Count >= 4 Then
    If InStrRev(oTable.Range.Text, "$") > 0 Then
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked on some, but not all my tables.  I'm racking my brain to find a common denominator that will work on all the tables.  The number of rows/columns and the placement of text varies from table to table.  So, is there any way to change this to find numeric text in the very last cell of each table, then replace that table with the placeholder? Or search for a "$" in the table, then replace that table with the placeholder?

Comment: Here is an attempt at written code.  Please instruct me as to my syntax, use of object, etc.

Sub AA_TablePlaceholder()

'
' AA_TablePlaceholder Macro
' Replaces tables with 4 or more columns and $ with a placeholder
'
Dim oTb As Table
Dim FindText As String

For Each oTb In ActiveDocument.Tables

'check if table has 4 or more columns
If oTb.Columns.Count >= 4 Then

FindText = "$"

With Selection
.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = FindText
End If
    Do While .Execute
    Selection.Delete
    Selection.TypeText Text:="[TABLE]"
Loop

End With
    End With
End Su

Comment: Thank you ever so much!  It works beautifully.  I actually combined the If with your previous suggestion to If the table has more than one row and equal to or more than four columns....